# Is there an Online version of LINQ Pad?

Tags: linq

Is there an Online version of LINQ Pad?

Comment: I doubt it. what would you want an Online version to do? What data sources would you hope it could query?

Comment: What would be the point of this?

Comment: Online LinqPad to XML would be great!

Comment: @RandyMinder, your comment reminds me of this one: "There is no reason for any individual to have a computer in their home.
- Kenneth Olsen, president and founder of Digital Equipment Corp., 1977."

Comment: @toddmo - Yeah, except I'm right. What is the point of an online version of LinqPad? LinqPad has been around for many years, and there currently is not an online version because nobody wants one and nobody has even added it as a suggestion.

Comment: @RandyMinder, dotnetfiddle. I guess that exists because no one wanted it or needed it, right?

Comment: @toddmo - I'm not sure what you find so hard to understand about all this, but I'll try to simplify. There is no online version of LinqPad because no one wants one. Just because dotnetfiddle exists doesn't mean there is any sort of demand for such a tool. In fact, I'd guess there is very little. Clear enough?

Comment: @RandyMinder, http://neue.cc/reference.htm lol

Answer (score 48):

There are two online services that I know of, which don't have the nice graphical features of LINQPad, but can be used as web-based C# (or VB.NET) scratch pads. I use them for testing the code in my StackOverflow answers on PCs without Visual Studio.

---

### Ideone

http://ideone.com/

It uses mono 2.8 and, thus, supports LINQ to objects.  Apart from C# and VB.NET, Ideone supports a variety of other languages.

---

### DotNetFiddle

https://dotnetfiddle.net/

DotNetFiddle lets you choose between .NET 4.5 and Roslyn and supports NuGet packages.

Comment: This appears to not be available anymore either?

Comment: @mkmurray: What makes you think that?

Comment: Nowadays there's also https://dotnetfiddle.net/, which offers a clean and simple online .NET editor.

Comment: I could not figure out how to add assembly reference in either of the two. For example, I want to run some Rx.NET code. Do not see how.

Comment: I usually use csharppad.com , but those suggested sites are good too.

Comment: is there any tool where we can have DB ready like Adventure works and we can go and start line query ?